# SQL: How to remove duplicates after sorting, while maintaining the sort order

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

```sql
SELECT miasto
FROM 
    wypozyczenia
    join czytelnik using (id_czyt)
    join ksiazka using (id_ks)
ORDER by cena desc
```

At the output, I get:

```
GDANSK
POZNAN
POZNAN
KRAKÓW
POZNAN
WARSZAWA
POZNAN
```

but need:

```
GDANSK
POZNAN
KRAKÓW
WARSZAWA
```

How to get rid of duplicates, but **keep the order?**

*(DISTINCT removes duplicates, but changes the order of cities)*

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation . . . but you need an aggregation function:

```
SELECT miasto
FROM wypozyczenia JOIN
     czytelnik using (id_czyt) JOIN
     ksiazka using (id_ks)
GROUP BY miasto
ORDER by MAX(cena) DESC;
```

If each `miasto` has only one `cena`, then this will preserve the order.  Otherwise, the order would be indeterminate after the aggregation.